# javascript: error combining DOM "id" and "name"

Tags: javascript, dom, attributes

I have some issues when combing a DOM calling on two attributes – id and name – when in a for-loop.

I have a html section with a table, where each cell has its own id  but the same name attribute:
`<td id="p1" name="f" ></td>
<td id="p2" name="f" ></td>
...
<td id="p47" name="f" ></td>`

Now I want to randomly put images in these cells with the following function:

```
 function begintest () {
    var i;
    var randnum;
    var randnum2;
    for(i=1;i<48;i++) {document.getElementById("p" + i).name="f";
    for(i=1;i<22;i++) { 
        randnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;    //picture of one sort
        randnum2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 47) + 1;  //random position between 1-47
        while(document.getElementById("p" + randnum2).name=="t") {  //check whether position taken
            randnum2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 47) + 1;  //random position between 1-47
        }
        document.getElementById("p" + randnum2).name = "t"; //true
        document.getElementById("p" + randnum2).style.backgroundImage = "url(i" + randnum + ".png)"; //put in image first sort
    }

    for(i=1;i<48;i++) { //picture of second sort
        if(document.getElementById("p" + i).name=="f") {    //if not filled with first sort
            randnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 26) + 7;   //take second sort
            document.getElementById("p" + i).style.backgroundImage = "url(i" + randnum + ".png)"; //put in image second sort
        }
    }

}
```

Yet I always get the debug info:

> TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
>   for the functions where a DOM reference with 2 attributes is used, such as:
>   if(document.getElementById("p" + i).name=="f")

How can this be? Is there another way to handle it?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code *per se*. If *document.getElementById* returns `null`, it means it didn't find the element. Attempting to access any property of `null` will throw an error.

Comment: When and where you call `begintest()`? It might be called before the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a slightly different approach.

1. *name attribute*: Why not using your own tag? Like "activated"? It would be less confusing to the system...
2. *Library*: I would use a library to manage that. jQuery works fine.

For example, this would return the `<td>` element with `id = 1`, only if it is activated:

```
jQuery("td#p1[activated]")
```

This would tell you whether the selected element is already filled in or not:

```
jQuery("td#p1").is("[activated]")
```

Comment: ok now i feel ashamed... I did make a typo. I simply used twice id=42, but missed id=41

Comment: with jQuery: I use a html platform within another platform – which does not support jQuery. yet your suggestion is indeed a lot easier!

Answer (score 0):

This may just be a copy-paste error but your first for loop is missing a closing brace.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using,

```
if(document.getElementById("p" + i).name=="f")
```

Use this version

```
if(document.getElementById("p" + i).getAttribute("name") =="f" )
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

This works (**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/34zBu/)**):

```
function beginTest() {
    var i,
        randomImage,
        randomP,
        p;
    for (i = 1; i < 48; i += 1) {
        p = document.getElementById('p' + i);
        p.name = 'f';       // using the name attribute as a flag
    }
    for (i = 1; i < 22; i += 1) {
        //check whether position taken
        while (p.name !== 't') {
            randomImage = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;    // picture of one sort
            p.name = 't';
            p.style.backgroundImage = 'url(i' + randomImage + '.png)';  // put in image first sort
            p.innerText = p.style.backgroundImage;
            randomP = Math.floor(Math.random() * 47) + 1;       // random position between 1-47
            p = document.getElementById('p' + randomP);         // cache DOM lookup
         }
    }
    for (i = 1; i < 48; i += 1) {                               // picture of second sort
        p = document.getElementById('p' + i);                   // cache DOM lookup
        if (p.name=="f") {        // if not filled with first sort
            randomImage = Math.floor(Math.random() * 26) + 7;       // take second sort
            p.style.backgroundImage = 'url(i' + randomImage + '.png)';  //put in image second sort
            p.innerText = p.style.backgroundImage;
        }
    }
}
beginTest();
```

Here's a more efficient way to do this (and **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/34zBu/2/)**):

```
function beginTest() {
    var i,
        randomImage,
        randomP,
        p,
        randArr =[];
    for (i = 1; i < 48; i += 1) {
        p = document.getElementById('p' + i);
        p.innerText = p.id  // visually distinguish which p elements do not have a background image
        randArr.push(i);
    }
    randArr.sort(function (a, b) {
        var randA = Math.floor(Math.random() * 47) + 1,
            randB = Math.floor(Math.random() * 47) + 1;
        return randA - randB;
    });
    for (i = 0; i < randArr.length; i += 1) {
        randomImage = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;    // picture of one sort
        p = document.getElementById('p' + randArr[i]);         // cache DOM lookup
        p.style.backgroundImage = 'url(i' + randomImage + '.png)';  // put in image first sort
        p.innerText = p.style.backgroundImage;
     }
}
beginTest();
```